# Graphics driver issue on Asus FX553VD and Kubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, kubuntu-netbook

I own an Asus FX553VD which comes with a **nVidia Geforce 1050 notebook** and an **integrated Intel graphics (on Kabylake 7700HQ)**. I installed Ubuntu 17.04, 17.10 and now Kubuntu 17.10. My problem is notebook works fine but I cannot reboot it. Sometimes after issuing reboot command or from menu it freezes and sometimes it just shows a blank screen then I should hold power button to power off system. Also I cannot run any tty session using **ctrl+alt+f(n)** keys since system freezes also. In Ubuntu everything was much worse, even freezing when I run a cpu heavy program. I can install nvidia driver but it consumes more power which drains battery and makes fans noisy as well. I even tried to install other distros like Antegos 17.11 but no success (Not even booting). Any ideas what can I do to solve the issue?

P.S. Also keyboard backlight cannot be changed.

Comment: I have your own computer. How do you start it? I have tried several versions of Linux but no part of me. What kernel do you use? How do I set the BIOS?
Did you turn off ACPI mode?

Comment: While booting in  grub menu press e, then add `nomodeset=0` after `quiet spash` so it becomes  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset=0"`, save and continue booting. Then it should boot. After that refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out how to get it to work. All problems are with graphics driver. If you wanna it to work with Intel graphics (which consumes less power) then edit grub and add `nouveau.modeset=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` section. Update grub, reboot and now everything should work as expected.